# Passing strings for MessageEmbed#setFooter is deprecated

Tags: discord, discord.js, warnings, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I'm getting this warning in the terminal when running my bot code:

(node:6220) DeprecationWarning: Passing strings for MessageEmbed#setFooter is deprecated. Pass a sole object instead.(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can ignore this message, it doesn't make any problem to the code, it's still working perfectly fine

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**D.JS v13 changes**

```js
// you used:
embed.setFooter("test")
// in discord.js v13:
embed.setFooter({
text: "test"
})
```